# synchronize web method calling a back end method

Tags: java, synchronization

I have written a Restful web service to send SMSs using a modem. The web method calls a method in a different package (sendSMS method) to send the SMS using smslib in Java. I am looking for a way to synchronize the method call by the web method. That is if 2 people call the web service at the same time, the web method     should call the sendSMS for one call and call it again after the previous call is complete. In other words, sendSMS should be called only once at a time. How do I make this synchronized call from my web method?

Comment: What is the problem? What have you tried? What is the Question?

Comment: I tried using the synchronized keyword in the sendSMS method. But it doesn't work.